# JSR223 Sampler to test Kerberos enabled AJAX based services

Tags: ajax, jmeter, performance-testing, kerberos

We have enabled kerberos based authentication on our RESTful services. At the moment I am load testing the website which these services support and need a way to call these. I followed the official site guide, to call the Kerberos backed services with normal HTTP Request sampler and Authorization Manager and it worked. But now I need to call some of the services from JSR223 Sampler to mimic parallel AJAX calls. Anyone has an idea on how to go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given you use [Apache HTTPClient 4 implementation](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/index.html) (default) something like:

```
import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.AuthManager;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy;
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
import java.net.URL;

AuthManager authManager = ((HTTPSamplerProxy) ctx.getPreviousSampler()).getAuthManager();
CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = ((AbstractHttpClient) client).getCredentialsProvider();
String localhost = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("httpclient.localaddress", "");
authManager.setupCredentials(client, new URL("http://your.url"), credentialsProvider, localhost);
```

References:

- [AuthManager.setupCredentials() JavaDoc](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/control/AuthManager.html#setupCredentials(org.apache.http.client.HttpClient,%20java.net.URL,%20org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider,%20java.lang.String))
- [How to Load Test AJAX/XHR Enabled Sites With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-ajaxxhr-enabled-sites-jmeter)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. I will check this and get back to you